# Remove 'rel' attribute of 'a' tag which is inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the `rel` attribute of the `a` inside `other class` without removing the one inside `myclass`.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('other class').document.getElementsByTagName("a").element.removeAttribute("rel");
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferre">MEC</a>
</div>

<div class="other class">
  <a = rel "nofollow noopener noreferrer">MEC</a>
</div>
```

I also tried using jQuery:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('other class').child;
for (var i = 0; i < activeLis.length; i++) {
  var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
    allLinks[i].removeAttribute("rel");
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr, plain JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Comment: I tried: document.getElementsByClassName('other class').document.getElementsByTagName("a").element.removeAttribute("rel");

Comment: tried too:$(document).ready(function() {
      var activeLis = document.getElementsByClassName('other class').child;
  for (var i = 0; i < activeLis.length; i++) {
       var allLinks=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++)
  {
  allLinks[i].removeAttribute("rel");
} 
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use :

```
$('.other').children('a').attr("rel","");
```

Or

```
$('.other').children('a').removeAttr("rel");
```

Comment: Strictly writing this is wrong, since it does not remove the atrribute.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` return node lists. As such you need to iterate through them, which is easier done with `querySelectorAll()`, calling `removeAttribute()` on the individual nodes. Try this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.other.class').forEach(function(el) {
  el.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(a) {
    a.removeAttribute("rel");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferre">MEC</a>
</div>

<div class="other class">
  <a rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">MEC</a>
</div>
```

The jQuery equivalent of this is:

```
$('.other.class > a').removeAttr("rel");
```

This is obviously assuming that you are selecting the `div` using two classes. If it's just a single class then use `.otherclass`